# DateList does not output the correct time, but Date does

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, raspberry-pi

**Bug fixed in 10.0.0+2014080602**

---

I noticed a strange thing when trying the new [astronomical data functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AstronomicalComputationAndData.html) in Mathematica 10 on my Raspberry Pi. The [`Sunrise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sunrise.html) and [`Sunset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sunset.html) functions return incorrect times. Then I started to play with time and date functions and I've discovered that [`Date`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Date.html) and [`DateList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DateList.html) return different results. As a reference, the output of both functions on my main computer:

```
Column[{Date[], DateList[],$TimeZone}]
```

> ```
> {2014,3,31,20,54,59.141095}
> {2014,3,31,20,54,59.141123}
> 2.
> ```

But on the Raspberry Pi:

> ```
> {2014,3,31,20,54,49.685639}
> {2014,3,31,19,54,49.778047}
> 1.
> ```

Looks like the `$TimeZone` is off, but `Date` ignores it. Let's look at the documentation of the two functions:

> Date[] uses whatever date and time have been set on your computer system. It performs no corrections for time zones, daylight saving time, etc.

vs

> DateList[] uses whatever date and time have been set on your computer system. It performs no corrections for time zones, daylight saving time, etc.

So they should return exactly the same output. There's a warning that "Date has been superseded by DateList since Version 6.0" but in this case it actually works better.
Why doesn't Mathematica detect the correct time zone and why does `Date` work, but `DateList` doesn't?

Comment: do this `Read["!date","String"] ` then `Close["!date"]`  I'm guessing its something to do with daylight savings time, but lets see how the sys clock is set in any case.

Comment: It gets the correct time: `"Mon Mar 31 22:59:02 CEST 2014"`.

Comment: So it looks like its giving you the standard time.  Should be reported as a bug I'd say.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with the January 29 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears as if this problem was a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in earlier versions of the RPi distribution.  The August 4, 2014 version behaves as expected.:

```
$Version
    Column[{Date[],DateList[],$TimeZone}]
(*
10.0 for Linux ARM (32-bit) (August 4, 2014)
{2014, 12, 17, 18, 30, 42.338928}
{2014, 12, 17, 18, 30, 42.339383}
-6.
*)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm it works with the latest version.